# Trigonometry road question

Tags: trigonometry

A road is at a constant gradient for 400m.  If the angle from the horizontal is 32°, at what height does the road climb?

Im a little confused at this so help would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

Let the Height of the road be $h$ metres . Then the road and the horizontal forms a right angle triangle with Height $h$ and hypotenuse $400$ metres.

Using trigonometry  :

$$\begin{align} \sin \theta & = \frac{\text{Height}}{\text{Hypotenuse}}
\\ \sin 32^o & = \frac h{400} \\ 
h &= \sin 32 \times 400 \\ 
h & = \boxed {\color{blue}{220.571 \text { metres }}} \end{align}
$$

Comment: Fallen Prince, I think you might have broken your calculator when you fell. You need to purchase a new calculator! $\sin 32^\circ \times 400=211.9677...$